# Android Set HorizontalScrollView to only sit at discrete values

Tags: android, user-interface

I've got a `HorizontalScrollView` that I'm programatically adding cards too. However currently the scrolling is continuous, you can be anywhere between the cards, but I'd like for it to be discrete, so each card is always centred to the screen and swiping left or right just moves to the next card, rather than being somewhere between the two.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are libraries that solve this problem, like [DiscreteScrollView](https://github.com/yarolegovich/DiscreteScrollView).

And if you can use a `RecyclerView` instead, it has built-in support for this behavior in the form of [`SnapHelper`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SnapHelper.html).